# Expo Client: Fast Refresh not working (React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am developing a React Native application using Expo Client, I am also using the android emulator from android studio to connect to see all my changes live.

However the fast refresh doesn't work, I can only see changes if I restart the development server which makes the workflow extremely long and tedious.

I have tried many fixes that are listed in these posts here [Link1](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4957) and here [Link2](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/828).

To summarise the fixes I have tried but did not solve my issues:

1. deleted package-lock.json and reinstall (using npm install --package-lock-only)
2. Deleting Expo app off the emulator, wiping emulator data and cold booting it then re installing Expo app
3. Clearing browser cache and turning on and off remote debugging js (this method is covered in the the first link)

None of these have worked for me.

I'm including the package.json file just this might be needed.

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.14",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.1",
    "expo-av": "~8.7.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Same issue.. I did nothing. What worked 2 days ago is not working now.

Comment: Have you found any work arounds that work even temporarily?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find it. In my case, fast refresh works with expo sdk40. But it still doesn't work on sdk38. I can't find anything about why...

Answer (score 9):

I solved my own problem as follows;

In project directory just run

```
rm -f ./.git/index.lock
```

I hope your problem is solved in this way.

Comment: Finally someone with the correct answer! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you made any updates to your metro packages try running

`npm install --save-dev metro metro-core`

I hope thismay also solve the issue for others.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

These days you need to make sure you have the `@expo/metro-runtime` (`npm install @expo/metro-runtime`) package and import it into your main entry point file (ie: App.js/index.js)

`import "@expo/metro-runtime"`